# Regex - Regular expression pattern failing on URL GET parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a URL GET variable replace, however the regular expression for checking whether the variable exists in amongst other GET variables is returning true when I am expecting it to return false.

The pattern I am using is: `&sort=.*&`

Test URL: `http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=asc`

Am I right to believe that this pattern should be returning false on the basis that their is no ampersand character following the sort parameter's value?

Full code:

```
var sort = getOptionValue($(this).attr('id'));
var url = document.URL;

if(url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    url = url+'?sort='+sort;
} else {
    if(url.search('/&sort=.*&/i')) {
        url.replace('/&sort=.*&/i','&sort='+sort+'&');
    }
    else if(url.search('/&sort=.*/i')) {
        url.replace('/&sort=.*/i','&sort='+sort);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right to believe that this pattern should be returning false on the basis that their is no ampersand character following the sort parameter's value?

Well, you are using [String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), which, according to the linked documentation:

> If successful, search returns the index of the regular expression inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1.

So it will return `-1`, or `0` or greater when there is a match. So you should test for `-1`, not truthiness.

Also, there is no need to pass the regexes as strings, you might as well use:

```
url.replace(/&sort=.*&/i,'&sort='+sort+'&');
```

Further, keep in mind that `replace` will create a new string, not replace in the string (strings in Javascript are immutable).

Finally, I don't see the need for searching for the string, and then replacing it -- it seems that you always want to replace `&sort=SOMETHING` with `&sort=SOMETHING_ELSE`, so just do that:

```
if(url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    url = url+'?sort='+sort;
} else {
    url = url.replace(/&sort=[^&]*/i, '&sort=' + sort);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript string function `search()` returns -1 if not found, not false. Your code should read:

```
if(url.search('/&sort=.*&/i') != -1) {
    url.replace('/&sort=.*&/i','&sort='+sort+'&');
}
else if(url.search('/&sort=.*/i') != -1) {
    url.replace('/&sort=.*/i','&sort='+sort);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check

```
if(url.search('/&sort=.*&/i') >= 0)
```

then it should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code

```
var url = 'http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=asc';
var vars = {};
  var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
console.log(vars);
//vars is an object with two properties: location and sort
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using

```
url.replace(/([?&])(sort=)([^&?]*)/, "$1$2" + sort);
```

The match broken down

Group 1 matches for ? or &
Group 2 matches sort=
Group 3 matches anything that is not a & or ?

Then "$1$2" + sort will replace all 3 group matches with the first 2 + your variable

examples using string "REPLACE" instead of your sort variable

```
url = "http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=asc&a=z"
url.replace(/([?&])(sort=)([^&?]*)/, "$1$2" + "REPLACE");
// => "http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=REPLACE&a=z"

url = "http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=asc"
url.replace(/([?&])(sort=)([^&?]*)/, "$1$2" + "REPLACE");
// => "http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=REPLACE"

url = "http://localhost/search?sort=asc"
url.replace(/([?&])(sort=)([^&?]*)/, "$1$2" + "REPLACE");
// => "http://localhost/search?sort=REPLACE"

url = "http://localhost/search?sort=asc&z=y"
url.replace(/([?&])(sort=)([^&?]*)/, "$1$2" + "REPLACE");
// => "http://localhost/search?sort=REPLACE&z=y"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The pattern I am using is: `&sort=.*&` Test URL:
>   `http://localhost/search?location=any&sort=asc`
>   Am I right to believe that this pattern should be returning false on
>   the basis that their is no ampersand character following the sort
>   parameter's value?

you are assuming right. But in your code you have `else if(url.search('/&sort=.*/i'))` which will match and thus still replace the value.

You should also note that your code would turn `http://localhost/search?sort=asc&location=any&some=more` into `http://localhost/search?sort=asc&some=more`. that's because because `.*` is greedy (trying to match as much as possible). You can avoid that by telling it to match as little as possible by appending a ? like so `.*?`.

That said, I believe you may be better off with a library that knows how URLs actually work. You're not compensating for parameter position, possible escaped values etc. I suggest you have a look at [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) and replace your wicked regex with

```
var uri = URI(document.URL), 
    data = uri.query(true); 

data.foo = 'bazbaz'; 
uri.query(data);
```